# Plugin [id: 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'] was not found in any of the following sources

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl, dagger-hilt

I get the following warning when I want to use @AndroidEntryPoint which is a property of hilt in my project.

```
 Expected @AndroidEntryPoint to have a value. Did you forget to apply the Gradle Plugin? (dagger.hilt.android.plugin)
```

When I try to add id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin' to the module level build.gradle file of my project, I get the following error.

```
org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'] was not found in any of the following sources:
```

I tried to add it to the build.gradle file at the Module level of the project as follows. They all give an error.

[image]

I tried to add it as a classpath to the project level build.gradle file, in this case I still get an error.

[image]

When I created the default project, a settings.gradle structure was created as follows. This is my first time using this build. My version of Android Studio Android Studio - Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Canary 13

[image]

Comment: Unrelated, but.... what is your beautiful colour scheme?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

After a long struggle, I solved the problem as follows;

I added a **resolutionStrategy** to **settings.gradle** as below.

```
 pluginManagement {
        repositories {...}
        plugins { ...}
     resolutionStrategy {
            eachPlugin {
                if( requested.id.id == 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin') {
                    useModule("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.39.1")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Then, when I added the hilt plugin as below to the module level **build.gradle** file, it was updated correctly.

```
plugins{
...
id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
}
```

Comment: But why? I have not added it and am still able to use Hilt. This error only comes (in my case) when I convert root `build.gradle` to `build.gradle.kts`. Just trying a bunch of random stuff and pasting here with one random way which coincidentally worked will not help in wrong run

Comment: @AtulGupta in my case the last version of gradle was making definitions in settings.gradle. Since classpath cannot be given in settings.gradle like build.gradle at project level, I solved it with this method.

Comment: Yup agree...That this particular string sequence definitely solved your issue but it clearly doesn't explain the root cause

Comment: I have added my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70556278/5028085) as well which explains why this config is required

Answer (score 134):

I am late for the answer.
I was also facing the same problem in Android Studio Bumblebee because of the new Gradle syntax for adding dependencies at the project level.

For adding Dagger Hilt in project-level you can use the following syntax:

```
id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android' version '2.41' apply false
```

At the time of writing this, the latest version is 2.41. It is in [mavenCentral repository](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.google.dagger.hilt.android/com.google.dagger.hilt.android.gradle.plugin/2.41/pom).

Comment: Nice, it was solved my issue

Comment: This solved my issue as well. First I tried this:   id("dagger.hilt.android.plugin") and it didn't work. Thanks

Comment: The version number is important. Initially I had '2.40.5' and it did not work. Changing it to '2.41' solved it.

Comment: Also, disabling offline mode in Android Studio forced the download to succeed for me.

Answer (score 23):

For adding `dagger hilt` to your project. Follow these steps

Add `hilt` dependencies to your module's `build.gradle`. I assume you are using `Kotlin`, otherwise you have to use `annotationProcessor` insted of `kapt` plugin.

```
dependencies {
  //..
  implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.39.1'
  kapt 'com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.39.1'
  //..
   }
```

Add `hilt gradle plugin` to project's `build.gradle`.

```
dependencies {
    //..
    classpath 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.39.1'
  }
```

Apply `kotlin-kapt` and `hilt` plugins to module `build.gradle`

```
plugins {
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
}
```

Comment: In gradle latest version I can't do this like classical method.

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: Are you sure 2.39.1 version of dagger hilt is really available? at the time of writing this comment 2.31-alpha is available.

Comment: @GopalSinghSirvi Currently, the latest version of the hilt is `2.40.5` which was released on Dec 7th, 2021. https://github.com/google/dagger/releases/tag/dagger-2.40.5

Answer (score 14):

`plugin{}` block in the root `build.gradle` is used to define the Gradle plugins that can be applied to root `build.gradle` and all(or some) the Gradle sub-projects.

The one **caveat** of using plugin block is that it only resolves plugin that is present in the *Gradle plugin portal*(see [doc](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugins_block)) or custom Maven and Ivy plugin repositories must contain plugin marker artefacts in addition to the artefacts which actually implement the plugin(see [doc](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugin_resolution_rules)).
In the case of the Android Gradle plugin and Hilt plugin, they have not published those plugins to *Gradle plugin portal* and they have also not published their [Plugin Marker Artifacts](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugin_markers)

Due to the above missing *Plugin Marker Artifacts* you need to manually resolve the plugin using [Plugin Resolution Rules](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugin_resolution_rules) at `settings.gradle` by adding the below code(this is specific to Hilt Gradle plugin for other you have to check different against `requested.id.id`)

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        // Your repo from where Gradle will search for Gradle plugins
    }
    plugins {
        // ...
    }
    resolutionStrategy {
        eachPlugin {
            if(requested.id.id == 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin') {
                    useModule("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:${requested.version}")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Much appreciated for the `{requested.version}`

Answer (score 11):

I faced the same problem, I solved the problem as follows:

First, add the `com.google.dagger.hilt.android` plugin to your project's root build.gradle  file:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.0' apply false
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android' version '2.42' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.0' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Then, apply the Gradle plugin and add these dependencies in your app/build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android'
}

android {
    ....................
    // Enable java 8
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {
    
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.38.1'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.38.1'
  
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Just you need to add this to project's root build.gradle file.

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    // other repositories...
    mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
    // other plugins...
    classpath 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.40'
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the correct solution no need for all the stuff you are told by AndroidEngineX the docs are here https://dagger.dev/hilt/gradle-setup.html

Comment: @D76X This is an older way to do it. In the latest Android studio, you have to do it using the way AndroidEngineX and other have suggested.

Answer (score 4):

use this configration in gradle root

```
         plugins {
         id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.0' apply false
         id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.0' apply false
        id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.21' apply false
        id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android' version '2.42' apply false
         }

       task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
         }
```

and  in 2nd gradle file

```
   plugins {    id 'com.android.application'    id 
   'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'    id 'kotlin-kapt'    id 
   'com.google.dagger.hilt.android' }
   android {    compileSdk 32
   defaultConfig {
   applicationId "com.example.hilttest"
   minSdk 21
   targetSdk 32
   versionCode 1
   versionName "1.0"

   testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"    }
   buildTypes {
   release {
       minifyEnabled false
       proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android- 
   optimize.txt'),    'proguard-rules.pro'
   }    }    compileOptions {
   sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
   targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8    }    kotlinOptions {
   jvmTarget = '1.8'    } }
   dependencies {
   implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'    implementation 
   'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'    implementation 
     `enter code here`'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0'    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'    implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.42'    kapt 'com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.42'
   // For instrumentation tests    androidTestImplementation  'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-testing:2.42'    kaptAndroidTest 'com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.42'
   // For local unit tests    testImplementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-testing:2.42'    kaptTest 'com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.42' } kapt {    correctErrorTypes = true }
```

Answer (score 1):

First, add the `hilt-android-gradle-plugin` plugin to your project's root `build.gradle`
 file:

```
buildscript {
    ...
    dependencies {
        def hilt_version = "2.39.1"
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.31"
        classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:$hilt_version"
    }
}
```

Then, apply the Gradle plugin and add these dependencies in your app/build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
  id 'kotlin-kapt' // for annotation processing
  id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
}

android {
    ...
}

dependencies {
    def hilt_version = "2.39.1"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$hilt_version"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:$hilt_version"
}

 
kapt {
    correctErrorTypes true
}
```

enable Java 8 in your project, add the following to the app/build.gradle

```
android {
    ...
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.toSttring()
}
```

Comment: You forgot to mention that this solution is almost copy-paste from the official documentation: https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android

Answer (score 1):

if u use gradle kotlin DSL

you must change kapt to ksp
https://developer.android.com/build/migrate-to-ksp

Answer (score 0):

All I need to add was this class path:

```
classpath 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.39.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue, I solved it by adding **com.google.dagger.hilt.android** to my root build.gradle()

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.0.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.0.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.20' apply false
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android' version '2.46.1' apply false
}
```

Then I applied this plug and added hilt dependencies in my app/build.gradle(Module:app)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
}


 dependencies{
    ----------------------------------------
      // dagger -hilt
        implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.46.1"
        kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.46.1"
        implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.7.2"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

in `build.gradle` project level, add this line `id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android' version '2.46.1' apply false`

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.0.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.0.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.20' apply false
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android' version '2.46.1' apply false
}
```

Then in `build.gradle` app level, add this line `id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android'`

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Kotlin** and **Android Studio Bumblebee 2023.1** or letter version then add the `hilt-android-gradle-plugin` plugin to your project's root `build.gradle` file:

```
plugins {
  ...
  id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android") version "2.44" apply false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you, like me, came across this because you were trying to add the dagger plugin into a precompiled convention plugin, none of the other answers will solve the problem. The solution is easy to gloss over, but note the part of [gradle's documentation on convention plugins](https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_convention_plugins.html#applying_an_external_plugin_in_precompiled_script_plugin) stating:

> external plugins need to be added as implementation dependencies before they can be applied in a precompiled script plugin

So, assuming a directory structure of:

```
├─build-conventions
│ ├─build.gradle.kts
│ ├─settings.gradle.kts
│ ├─src
│ │ ├─main
│ │ │ └─kotlin
│ │ │   ├─myproject.hilt-conventions.gradle.kts
│ │ │   └─[...]
├─app
│ └─[...]
├─build.gradle
├─settings.gradle
```

Rather than adding the hilt plugin as a versioned plugin in the root `build.gradle.kts` as you would do to get hilt to function in the `:app` module, you will instead need to add the following to `build-conventions/build.gradle.kts`:

```kotlin
// build-conventions/build.gradle.kts

dependencies {
    implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.47")
}
```

Then you will be free to apply the hilt plugin as usual to your convention plugin:

```kotlin
// build-conventions/src/main/kotlin/myproject.hilt-conventions.gradle.kts

plugins {
    id("kotlin-kapt")
    id("dagger.hilt.android.plugin")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this: Gradle Build Setup

```html
plugins {
  // other plugins...
  id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android' version '2.48.1' apply false
}
```

That works for me (although I didn’t use the apply false; I think that’s only if you have a parent project with sub projects). Note that the plugin name is different (‘com.google.dagger.hilt.android’ vs ‘dagger.hilt.android.plugin’), and that a version is specified; it didn’t work until I specified a version.`enter code here`